# Fermion field in $U(1)$ gauge theory

Tags: differential-geometry, field-theory, gauge-theory, fermions, yang-mills

I'm studying Nakahara's Geometry, topology and physics chapter 10.

In section 10.4 on page 391, the book writes:

> In physics, we often need to differentiate sections of a vector bundle which is associated with a certain principle bundle. For example, a charged scalar field in QED is regarded as a section of a complex line bundle associated with a $U(1)$ bundle $P(M,U(1))$. Differentiating sections covariantly is very important in constructing gauge-invariant actions.

My questions: what about fermions like electrons? Are they sections of a certain bundle? And how would we define covariant derivative $D_\mu=\partial_\mu+ieA_\mu(x)$ mathematically for fermions then?

Comment: Related question: [Covariant derivative for spinor fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7418/covariant-derivative-for-spinor-fields)

Comment: Wikipedia: [Spinor bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor_bundle) and [Spin connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_connection)

Comment: @Ghoster Can we construct a spinor bundle given a fiber bundle?

Comment: A spinor bundle is a particular kind of fiber bundle. An arbitrary fiber bundle can’t be turned into a spinor bundle.